# Extracting value from an MPX bounds register into a general purpose register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel

Intel's Memory Protection Extensions provide four new 128-bit bounds registers, `BND0` to `BND3`, each storing a pair of 64-bit lower bound (LB) and upper bound (UB) values of a buffer.

**How can I extract the lower bound's 64-bit value (i.e. `%BND0[0-63]` into a 64-bit general purpose register (i.e.`%RAX`)?**

The problem as I understand it is that Intel's instruction set doesn't provide a way to directly do this. I've consulted Intel's MPX Enabling Guide (see download at bottom of [this link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-memory-protection-extensions-enabling-guide)) and found that there is a `BNDMOV b/m, b` instruction that will store lower bounds and upper bounds in a bounds register to memory or *another register*. However it appears that the *another register* must be a bounds register itself because it's not possible to fit the 128-bit bounds register into a 64-bit general purpose register.

Additionally, as far as I can tell, there is no way to get just the lower bounds out of a bounds register by using a half-width sibling register (i.e. `%EAX` contains the value of the lower half of `%RAX`). Likewise, there is no addressing `%BND#.LB`, even though *fig. 14* on *pg. 50* of the *MPX Enabling Guide* shows a debugger watching those values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you can't. It seems you're supposed to use memory (with `BNDMOV` or `BNDSTX`) if you need the value of a bound register. `BND0.LB` is probably just the debugger notation and not an actual register.

Comment: This is what I'm afraid of. I'm going to leave the question open for a couple of days to see if anyone knows a way to get around the instruction set's limitation. If not, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: is there a reason you don't want / can't go through memory? might be good to mention it in the question.

Comment: I can't go into too many details because it's associated with a research prototype that we haven't yet published. But the short answer is that we want to avoid leaving traces of what value is contained in those MPX registers lying around in memory.

Comment: Additionally, there's the problem that our prototype won't be using the MPX runtime, and therefore the bounds table that is referenced by `BNDSTX`/`BNDLDX` won't exist.

Answer (score 5):

> This is an **experimental** solution, I don't have a CPU with MPX support at hand.
>   My work is purely theoretical, I can't tell if it will fail miserably due to some quibble on a real hardware.

---

As [Igor said in is complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43504370/5801661) there is no instruction to read a `bnd` register without passing through memory.
That's the end of the story.

As [Mattew expressed his concern about spilling the value of the `bnd` register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503244/extracting-value-from-an-mpx-bounds-register-into-a-general-purpose-register#comment74068448_43504370) I though of an indirect way to read the `bnd` register.

The bottom of the line being that due to their nature the MPX let a programmer perform a [dichotomic search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomic_search) on the value of a `bnd` register.

I'll use `bndcl` as reference throughout this answer. The dual, `bndcu`, with the considerations about the one complement format, is similar.

The instruction `bndcl` generates an exception #BR if the value of the register lower bound LB is higher than the address A tested.
What is required is to translate the conditions A < LB and A ≥ LB into a numeric value in a register or a flag.
Basically, if available and accessible, the `bndstatus` register's field EC (Error Condition) is what we are looking for: it is 1 if `bndcl` failed, 0 otherwise.
Alternatively one can handle the #BR exception (or any exception the OS reifies as `bndcl` generates only #BF and #UD) by setting a variable/register to 1. If said register is reset before executing `bndcl` then it will reflect the result of the check.
Care must be taken as the `rip` points to the offending `bndcl` instruction.

Long story short, one need something like

```
 bndcl:
    A < LB ⇒ ECX = 1 
    A ≥ LB ⇒ ECX = 0
```

With these prerequisites we can perform a binary search on the values of the lower bound.
There is one small caveat: we can't test for equality, only for *greater than or equal*.
This means: 1) we perform a fixed number of comparisons (slightly greater than 64) and 2) we need an extra final step to determine the exact address.

To understand point 2) just consider searching the values 14 and 15 in an array from 0 to 15 inclusive:

```
       15                          14

Pivot    Step   Cmp         Pivot    Step   Cmp
 8        4      ≥           8        4      ≥
 12       2      ≥           12       2      ≥
 14       1      ≥           14       1      ≥ (Can't stop here)
 15       0      ≥           15       0      ≥
```

---

My CPU doesn't support the MPX, so I'll assume the existence of a macro `bndclex` that perform the check of `bndcl` and set `ecx` as said above.

```
;Get the bnd0 lower bound without storing it into memory
;It uses a dichotomy search

get_bnd0_lb: 
 mov rax, 4000_0000_0000_0000h  ;Half-range
 lea rbx, [rax*2]               ;Address to check


_check:

 ;D O   T H E   B O U N D    C H E C K 

 bndclex _bnd0, rbx

 ;ecx = 01 if rbx < bnd0.lb
 ;ecx = 00 if rbx >= bnd0.lb

 ;S E T   T H E   C F 

 not ecx
 shr ecx, 1                     ;CF = 0   IF rbx < bnd0.lb
                                ;     1   IF rbx >= bnd0.lb

 ;A D D / S U B   T H E   H A L F   R A N G E 

 sbb rcx, rcx           ;rcx =  0 IF rbx < bnd0.lb
                                ;      -1 IF rbx >= bnd0.lb

 sub rbx, rcx                   ;rbx = rbx     IF rbx < bnd0.lb
                                ;      rbx +1  IF rbx >= bnd0.lb

 xor rcx, rax                   ;rcx = rax     IF rbx < bnd0.lb
                                ;      NOT rax IF rbx >= bnd0.lb

 add rbx, rcx                   ;rbx = rbx + rax      IF rbx < bnd0.lb
                                ;      rbx + NOT rax + 1 
                                ;    = rbx + (-rax)   IF rbx >= bnd0.lb

 shr rax, 1                     ;Halve half-range
jnz _check

 ;C H  E C K    T H E   E X A C T   A D D R E S S

 bndclex _bnd0, rbx

 ;ecx = 01 if rbx < bnd0.lb
 ;ecx = 00 if rbx >= bnd0.lb

 lea rax, [rbx + rcx]

 ret
```

The algorithm works by setting the initial pivot P<sub>0</sub> to the half of the 64-bit address range and the initial S<sub>0</sub> step equal to 1/4 of the address range.
Then at each step it moves the pivot to P<sub>i+1</sub> = P<sub>i</sub> ± S<sub>i</sub> and halves the step  S<sub>i+1</sub> = S<sub>i</sub> / 2.

This algorithm leaks the number of zeros in the lower bound of the `bnd` register as the number of exceptions generated but doesn't store the value in memory.
One could generate synthetic #BR exceptions to workaround that.

---

The implementation of the `bndclex` macro - or better its elimination - is left to the OP as that strongly depends on the environment.
Mine was as simple as

```
%macro bndclex 2

 xor ecx, ecx           ;RCX = 0
 lea r8, [rcx+1]        ;r8 = 0

 cmp %2, QWORD [REL %1 %+ .lb]            
 cmovb rcx, r8          ;RCX = 1 if %2 < lower bound

%endmacro
```

Comment: This is a really clever, albeit indirect way to "read" the value. I will have to take this idea and try to implement it in our prototype's microbenchmark to see what is the relative performance cost of doing up to 64 of the binary search's pivot subroutines. For cleverness alone, I wish I could award more than one up-vote.

Comment: @MatthewCole : You could offer a bounty on the question and then ultimately award it to Margaret or even a more clever answer (if one exists)

Comment: @MatthewCole Thanks :)

Comment: As for testing - the Intel SDE supports MPX: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator

Comment: Thank you @MichaelPetch! I've never used the Intel SDE, that's very interesting.

Comment: talk about overkill :) still, cool idea! I wonder I this can be used to bypass MPX protections somehow.